# Large Format Wet Saw - 12"x48" Porcelain Planks

Tags: tile, saw, wet, porcelain

New to tile, I'm laying 3500 sq ft on a concrete slab. Planks are 12"x48". I'm going to invest in a good wet saw, but I'm having trouble finding a saw I can rip 48" planks. Also, cross cut of 12" seems a bit large as well.

Any saw recommendations or tricks of the trade?

Comment: Sorry, I've never done anything like that so I don't have any advice. But 3500' is a LOT - by the time you're done, you'll be an expert!

Comment: Recommendation would be **not** go with a tile size that's going to be a huge pain in the rear, but I expect that course is already laid in by forces possibly beyond your control. Hard to cut, hard to level (look up "tile lippage",) hard to handle without breaking...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Having the desire to get good, straight, accurate rips on my 48" porcelain planks, I was having trouble finding a wet tile saw that could do this without flipping the tile around or coming up with a work-around.

I discovered bridge saws. With a bridge saw, the tile lays stationary and the motor and blade are pulled through the material on a rail or bridge above the work piece platform.

There are many manufacturers of bridge saws, a quick search for the term will result in many options.

Answer (score 3):

I suspect the only° practical way to go here would be a "handheld circular-saw format" wet saw and a cutting guide. Someone probably makes a full-scale tablesaw-wetsaw, but that will be rare and thus **very** expensive.

What I'm thinking of when I say cutting guide are the systems where a rail clamps to the workpiece and the saw baseplate is connected to the rail so that it travels along the rail in a straight line. I did note some more typical "rip guides" that just clamp on the saw and ride the edge of the material when I did a quick search on **handheld wet tile saw** - those *can* work if you maintain consistent pressure.

°I suppose on further thinking that with an appropriate "tiny tile tablesaw" which are common and inexpensive you really just need auxiliary tables and fences (that I suspect you may have to build or adapt from other things) to manage your outsize tiles. You don't really need a bigger blade, you just can't manage the cuts with the table they give you. So you make a big table the tiny saw sits in. You can't do that with the ones that have permanently attached parts sticking up other than the blade.

Answer (score -2):

Simple idea: Buy the biggest standard saw bench you can find (for tiles, wet cut, strong motor, biggish blade) and mount it into an old table, by cutting out a section in its top. That will give your tiles the support they need, and also give you a chance to make a guide parallel to the blade, or just use a strip of wood held with clamps at either end.